# Always getting failed to resolve support-v4

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I work in both machine (mac and windows). and android studio in both machine is configured similarly. In mac same code is working perfectly but in windows am getting always build error "Failed to resolve support-v4". Am stuck here and need solution. I have removed support repository using sdk manager and re installed again but no luck. my support library verion is 27.1.1 .  Below am giving both build.gradle file. Please give me suggestion or clue to fix this

my project level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
    classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    google()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
minSdkVersion = 19
targetSdkVersion = 27
compileSdkVersion = 27
buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
supportLibraryVersion = '27.1.1'
daggerVersion = '2.5'
retrofitVersion = '2.4.0'

rxJavaVersion = '2.1.13'
rxAndroidVersion = '2.0.2'

butterknifeVersion = '8.8.1'
loggerVersion = '3.4.1'
annotationVersion = '10.0-b28'
timberVersion = '4.7.0'
crashVersion = '2.6.2'
constraintLayoutVersion = '1.1.2'

fbAccountKitVersion = '4.+'
firebaseMessagingVersion = '17.1.0'
firebaseCoreVersion = '16.0.1'
playServiceVersion = '15.0.1'

picassoVersion = '2.71828'
eventBusVersion = '3.0.0'

tedBottomPickerVersion = '1.1.0'
tedPermissionVersion = '2.2.0'

}
```

my app level buil.gradle file is

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias '******'
        keyPassword '********'
        storeFile file('keystore/******.jks')
        storePassword '******'
    }
}

compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

//app versioning
def versionMajor = 1
def versionMinor = 1
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 3

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "project.passenger.oye.flow.oyebuddy"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
    versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}-Build-${versionBuild}"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    // Enabling multiDex support.
    multiDexEnabled true

    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false

        debuggable true

    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'

        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

    }
}

// Specifies flavor dimensions.
flavorDimensions "countryWise"

productFlavors {

    bangladeshFlavor {
        applicationId "project.passenger.oye.flow.oyebuddy"
        versionNameSuffix "-bd"
        dimension "countryWise"
    }
    nepalFlavor {
        applicationId "project.passenger.oye.flow.oyebuddy.nepal"
        versionNameSuffix "-nepal"
        dimension "countryWise"
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

packagingOptions.excludes = [
        'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES',
        'META-INF/LICENSE',
        'META-INF/LICENSE.txt',
        'LICENSE.txt',
        'LICENSE',
        'META-INF/license.txt',
        'META-INF/NOTICE',
        'NOTICE',
        'asm-license.txt',
        'META-INF/NOTICE.txt',
        'META-INF/notice.txt',
        'META-INF/ASL2.0',
        'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
]
}

repositories {
jcenter()
mavenCentral()
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

implementation project(':myDirectionLib')
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

//cons layout
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$rootProject.constraintLayoutVersion"

//due to mixed version
implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

//account kit facebook
implementation "com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:$rootProject.fbAccountKitVersion"
compileOnly "org.glassfish:javax.annotation:$rootProject.ext.annotationVersion"

//dagger2
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.daggerVersion"

annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.daggerVersion"

//retrofit2 / okhttp3
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.ext.retrofitVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.ext.retrofitVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$rootProject.ext.retrofitVersion"

implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$rootProject.ext.loggerVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$rootProject.ext.loggerVersion"

//rxjava2
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rootProject.ext.rxJavaVersion"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.ext.rxAndroidVersion"

//butterknife
implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$rootProject.ext.butterknifeVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$rootProject.ext.butterknifeVersion"

//logger
implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$rootProject.ext.timberVersion"

//play service
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$rootProject.ext.playServiceVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$rootProject.ext.playServiceVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:$rootProject.ext.playServiceVersion"

//due to mixed version
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$rootProject.ext.playServiceVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:$rootProject.ext.playServiceVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:$rootProject.ext.playServiceVersion"

//firebase / fcm
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$rootProject.ext.firebaseCoreVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$rootProject.ext.firebaseMessagingVersion"

// fabric / crashlytics
implementation("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$rootProject.ext.crashVersion@aar") {
    transitive = true
}

//image loading / imageview
implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$rootProject.ext.picassoVersion"
implementation 'cn.gavinliu.android.lib:ShapedImageView:0.8.5'

//event bus
implementation "org.greenrobot:eventbus:$rootProject.ext.eventBusVersion"

//for image picker single/multiple mode
implementation "gun0912.ted:tedbottompicker:$rootProject.ext.tedBottomPickerVersion"

//for permission listener
implementation "gun0912.ted:tedpermission:$rootProject.ext.tedPermissionVersion"



}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Just go to settings->execution and development->gradle and uncheck offline work now click on apply and try gradle sync it would work